# ElasticSearch bulk operation - omit response

Tags: optimization, elasticsearch, bulk

I was just wondering if there was any parameter / method to make a bulk request through the ElasticSearch REST api without a response being returned.

Trying to squeeze as much network performance as I can out of it, and I don't care about the result of the bulk operations in my use-case. Since I am rapidly inserting in batches of 20,000 at the moment I imagine I would save a decent amount of data transfer overhead by omitting them.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm replying to an old question here, but I faced the same question and found this page.

I'm not sure if this is something new in Elasticsearch since the question was asked, but you can use the "filter_path" query parameter: [See the API docs](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#response-filtering)

If you add "?filter_path=took,errors" to your "_bulk" query, the "items" are omitted from the response.

Comment: Thanks man! It's funny that that on ElasticSearch forums and on GitHub issues they officially say it's not possible....

Comment: Also you can use `took,errors,items.*.error` instead of `took,errors` to return verbose errors for items that failed to be proceeded. Normally, when no errors, you will get back only `took` and `errors`, but if at least one error happened, you will get back verbose messages which is helpful during debugging

Answer (score -1):

IMO, "_bulk" endpoint doesn't provide any such mechanism. You should however look at increasing your "refresh_interval", to allow for ElasticSearch to ack your indexing requests faster. This has a side-effect of making data not available for search immediately, so it depends on the actual scenario.
There are numerous other settings to tweak the indexing throughput like various buffers used while indexing. You can also look at making sure not extra analysis is done on the fields which don't need analysis.